# Excess Bunching - Bunching Estimator (Saez 2010)

Tags: mathematical-statistics, nonparametric, econometrics

[Saez (2010)](http://eml.berkeley.edu/~saez/saezAEJ10bunching.pdf) defines excess bunching at the kink as the area under the density in the dominated region:

$$
B = \int^{z^*+d z^*}_{z^*} h(z)dz \approx h(z^*)dz^*
$$
where income $z$ is distributed according to a smooth density function $h(z)$.

$B$ is interpreted as the number of individuals who bunch at the kink. Why can we interpret $B$ as a number. I would interpret $B$ as the probability of $z$ falling into the interval ${z^*}$ to $z^*+d z$.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

$B$ isn't a probability because it's mass taken from a part of the distribution that is missing after the policy change. To see this better you can go back to the theoretical model where he shows the effect of a tax change on individuals' utility.

[image]

Here all the individuals who are between $z^{*}$ and $z^{*}+dz^{*}$ are in the so-called dominated region after the tax increase. That means they are better off moving to the bunching point $z^{*}$. So the number of individuals who bunch at this point is captured by the height of the density at $h(z^{*})dz^{*}$ which tells you the mass (i.e. the number of individuals) who are at the taxable income which equals $z^{*}$. Saez mostly represents these density estimates via histograms with bin sizes of 1,000$ and the confusing part about this is that he never reports the relative frequencies on the left vertical axis, otherwise it would be more immediate from his graphs.

Comment: Thank you for your nice explanations! I am still a bit confused (mathematically):  Usually, the integral over a density function gives a probability, e.g $$  \Pr [a \le X \le b] = \int_a^b f_X(x) \, dx, $$ where $X$ is a random variable with density $f_X$. Why is this not the case for the equation cited above?

Comment: Oh I see what you mean, ok. So for very small changes $dz^{*}$ this integral is a tiny area and hence approximates the height $h(z^{*})dz^{*}$, i.e. the mass at point $z^{*}$. That's actually why he makes the assumption in the paper that the tax rate change is "small" such that this approximation holds (otherwise it doesn't). See for instance [here](http://goo.gl/551sGr) why the height of a pdf at a point is not necessarily a probability

Comment: @Francesco if you're not satisfied with the answer or if something is unclear please feel free to ask for further clarification

Comment: Thanks again! I am still puzzled: We know that an integral over an pdf gives a probability. Because $h(z^*)dz^*$ approximates the integral, it also should be a probability. My feeling is that the literature is a bit imprecise. My interpretation is as follows:  We know that the support of $z$ is mapped to the total population mass that is equal to one. In this case the probability that $z$ falls into a certain interval is the same as the fraction of individuals who choose a value of $z$ within this interval. But: It is still a fraction, not a number.

Comment: @Francesco Yes but the integral $\int^{z^* + dz^*}_{z^*}$ is a very small range given that $dz^*$ is a [very small change](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Differential_%28infinitesimal%29), hence it's approximately the same as the height. And if you look at the y-axis of the pdf which is $f(x)$ you can read of the frequency from the height. So even though we have an integral here it's over such a small area that it approximates a point in the pdf (the height).

Comment: You're most welcome :)